# Drop Column from an index mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, database-indexes

i'am having these indexes on my table:

```
mysql> SHOW INDEXES from sous_categories;
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| sous_categories |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id_sous_categorie | A         |          16 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| sous_categories |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | categorie_id      | A         |          16 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

and i want to remove the second column, by checking [MySQL INDEX STATMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-index.html), i figured out that i can drop only by index_name, but in my case both has the same key_name.
How can i do that please ? (I know it's possible because i can do it with phpmyadmin but i want to know how to do it with command line)

Comment: This is one index, with two columns.

Comment: So i can't drop the second column ? i'll edit the question

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks for your comment, i tried that at the first, but the query result not displayed in good form...

Comment: Well, i tried copy as HTML from Terminal and it works sorry,

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Comment: *i want to remove the second column* Why? this will change your data consistency logic. Moreover, if the table contains some data than it is possible that the primary key by one column only cannot be created due to the duplicated data.

Comment: Exactly, i wanna implement a new data logic so i need to remove this one

Comment: @Akina Doesn't the column 'non_unique' of the index description tell that there is no duplicate data in either of the index columns? (Your hint holds in general, of course) @E Epsylon When revamping your data logic, wouldn't you alter the table definition anyway (implying that the index has to be rebuilt, so nothing is lost in re-defining It from scratch)?

Comment: MySQL does not have an alter index option so your only command line option is drop followed by create which is what I suspect phpmyadmin is doing for you

Comment: *i wanna implement a new data logic so i need to remove this one* Drop existing primary key and add needed one with new index expression.

Comment: @collapsar 'non-unique' is the whole index option, not separate column in the index expression option.

Comment: Well, I did what you told me @Akina and i'm working fine now, should i  delete the post ?

Comment: @EEpsylon No. This is a Q&A repository designed to help people running in troubles others have seen before. Obviously this won't work if the trouble descriptions get deleted quickly. Substandard questions will be handled by the community.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE sous_categories
    DROP PRIMAR KEY,
    ADD PRIMARY KEY(id_sous_categorie);
```

However, to be the PK, `id_sous_categorie` must be Unique (no dups) and `NOT NULL`.

The only effects will be

- Time spent rebuilding the table.  (Any change to the PK requires a rebuild.)
- A fatal error if `id_sous_categorie` is not already unique.  (Previously the pair of columns was constrained to be unique, but not each column.)